# extra argument in call alamofire swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to make an alamofire post request, I am sending a parameter and a body , as following:

```
  static func sendFeedbackResultOldCustomer(customerId: String?,fbackAnswers:String? ,answers: String?, completion: @escaping (Bool , String?) ->() ){

        let parameters: Parameters = ["customer_id":customerId!,"customer_new":"0","x-session":getXSession()]
        request(urlString: APIStrings.feedbackSent, parameters: parameters, method: .post, headers: nil, encoding: answers, updateXsession: false) { (success, error, errorMsg, response) in
            if(success) {
                completion(true, nil)
            }
            else {
                completion(false, response?.result.error as? String)
            }
        }
    }
```

the request code:

```
fileprivate static func request (urlString: String!, parameters: Parameters?, method: HTTPMethod, headers: HTTPHeaders?,encoding: String!, updateXsession: Bool, completion: @escaping(Bool, Error?, String?, DataResponse<Any>?) ->()) {
        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, headers: headers,encoding:encoding).responseJSON { (response) in// here is the error (extra argument method in call)
            let contentType = response.response?.allHeaderFields["X-Session"] as? String
            if (updateXsession)
            {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(contentType, forKey: "x-session")
            }

            let success = checkIfSuccess(response: response)
            if(success){
                completion(success, nil, nil, response)
            } else {
                completion(success, response.error, "Failed", nil)
            }
        }
```

in the alamofire request, im getting the following error : Extra argument in call. any idea whats going on?

parametes im sending:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["customer_id":customerId!,"customer_new":"0","x-session":getXSession()]
```

body im trying to send:

```
X_types = [{"type_id":"17","value":"3"},{"type_id":"12","value":"test"},{"type_id":"14","value":"4"},{"type_id":"19","value":"3"},{"type_id":"16","value":"4"},{"type_id":"13","value":"3"},{"type_id":"18","value":"4"},{"type_id":"15","value":"4"},{"type_id":"2","value":"4"},{"type_id":"11","value":"1"},{"type_id":"1","value":"3"},{"type_id":"8","value":"3"},{"type_id":"6","value":"2"},{"type_id":"4","value":"22-09-2017 - 12:1"},{"type_id":"5","value":"Test"}]
```

X_types is been sent in the encoding , as a string (x_types is as string type)

Answer (score 0):

The signature for alamofire request is: `public func request(_ url: URLConvertible, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod = default, parameters: Parameters? = default, encoding: ParameterEncoding = default, headers: HTTPHeaders? = default)`. I think you have mismatched the signature.

Try

```
let request = Alamofire.request(url, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
request.responseJSON { response in 

}
```

Comment: and where can I send the body in this case? if I changed the encoding to JSONEncoding.default ??

Comment: Pass body as paramters, parameters will be of dictionary type `[String : Any]`
.

Comment: but I have a parameter type dictionary [String: Any], shall I send the body also in the parameter? I've tried it, it didn't work, it should be sent in the body

Comment: You are doing it right, you have to pass parameters as `[String: Any]`

Comment: how should I send the body? it cannot be sent in the parameter.

Comment: Body should always be sent as parameters, can you show me how you are constructing parameters or your body part.

Comment: I see answers as encoding, what is that?

Comment: encoding, is where I am sending the body, encoding, in the request, receives a type string, which contains the body above which I want to send.

Comment: In that case directly assign your json as parameters i.e. parameters = X_types

Comment: and what to do with the parameter? where shall I send it?